# Where can I find the average wind speed, snow load and seismic ss value by zip code and building code

Tags: gis

I am developing a online quote tool for solar panels, which needs wind speed, snow load and and seismic ss data to calculate the maximum span of the rails of the system.

Comment: Ask in [gis](gis.stackexchange.com)

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157788/where-can-i-find-the-average-wind-speed-snow-load-and-seismic-ss-value-by-zip-c